# Find the students whose time interval clashes with themselves?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, css

In simple words.
I have a query which displays this table. (students usn is group concatenated, and displayed the whole row with foreach).

row 1 => subject 1 - 22/07/2015 - 08:00 - **1XX10XX086**, 1XX10XX087, 1XX09XX088

row 2 => subject 2 - 22/07/2015 - 09:00 - 1XX10XX086, 1XX10XX087, 1XX09XX088

row 3 => subject 3 - 22/07/2015 - 08:00 - 1XX10XX096, **1XX10XX086**, 1XX09XX098

row 4 => subject 4 - 22/07/2015 - 10:00 - 1XX10XX096, 1XX10XX086, 1XX09XX098

row 5 => subject 5 - 22/07/2015 - 08:00 - 1XX10XX106, 1XX10XX107, 1XX09XX108

How shall i highlight in jquery or html or php or from anything 1XX10XX086 roll no as he cant attend both the subject 1, subject 3 at the same day and same time but can attend subject 2 as it is at different time slot. how shall i hight light them.?

Comment: store the `students usn` information properly in a link table

Comment: Properly. please define properly as Its a group concatinated string.

Comment: every time you want to access this information and look at it in different ways, you will have to do error-prone and performance intensive string manipulations to get your results. the normal way to do this would be to use a link table where you store the link information from a subject id to a student id. this way you can easily access the info about what subjects a student is enrolled in ( and many more questions which will come later )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you get already your table and you want highlight your required td with some jquery, so you can do the next for example:

The idea is to loop all your  table rows and compare  `td` with date info if two rows have td with the same date then split and compare the `td` with groups info, if the first array(all values in group td exploded by `,`) do contains one or more values from the second array highlight both.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('tr').each(function( index ) {
        var current=$(this);
        current.nextAll('tr').each(function( index ) {
            if(current.children( ".date" ).html()==$(this).children( ".date" ).html()){
                var child=$(this);
                var a = current.children( ".groups" ).html().split(',');
                var b = child.children( ".groups" ).html().split(',');
                   $.each( a, function( key, value ) {
                       if($.inArray( value,  b ) != -1){
                         
                         ///EDIT
                         current.children( ".groups" ).html(current.children( ".groups" ).html().replace(
                              new RegExp(value, 'g'), '<span class=Markme >'+value+'</span>'
                          ));
                         child.children( ".groups" ).html(child.children( ".groups" ).html().replace(
                              new RegExp(value, 'g'), '<span class=Markme >'+value+'</span>'
                          ));
                          
                         /////////
                       }
                      
                  });
                
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.Markme {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table  border="1">
    <tr>
        <td class="subject">subject 1</td>
        <td class="date">22/07/2015 - 08:00</td>
        <td class="groups">1XX10XX086,1XX10XX087,1XX09XX088</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="subject">subject </td>
        <td class="date">22/07/2015 - 09:00</td>
        <td class="groups">1XX10XX086,1XX10XX087,1XX09XX088</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="subject">subject 3</td>
        <td class="date">22/07/2015 - 08:00</td>
        <td class="groups">1XX10XX096,1XX10XX086,1XX09XX098</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="subject">subject 4</td>
        <td class="date">22/07/2015 - 10:00</td>
        <td class="groups">1XX10XX096,1XX10XX086,1XX09XX098</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="subject">subject 5</td>
        <td class="date">22/07/2015 - 08:00</td>
        <td class="groups">1XX10XX106,1XX10XX107,1XX09XX108</td>
    </tr>
    
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, Solved the problem. just want to highlight only the reg numbers not the whole td.

Comment: See Edits :)   .....

Comment: Super dude. Thanks for it. Expect mutual help from me. Ask anytime.

Answer (score 0):

create an array with datetime and check with its values

```
<?php $dateArr=array('22/07/2015 - 08:00'=>array('1XX10XX086', '1XX10XX087', '1XX09XX088'));
    if(in_array('1XX10XX086',$dateArr['22/07/2015 - 08:00'])){
        /* highlight*/
    } else {
        array_push($dateArr['22/07/2015 - 08:00'],$element);
    }
?>
```

Hope you are getting what i wanted to explain. If not, please comment so i can edit my code.

Comment: Thanks, but did not get you properly. please refer to my last updated on this question. For 22nd 8 O clock he has sub1 sub3 but for the same day at 9 O clock he has sub2 he can attend sub2 but cant sub1 sub3 at the same time.